# Python creates a huge file that cannot be opened

Tags: python, file

I have a text file which contains lists of tuples in string format, I need to read the each line and normalize it. I'm also converting the tuples in to float. Once the normalization is completed, the normalized data needs to be written to a file. Here is the program written to do this, the programs runs fine, however it ends up creating a huge file, in this case 126MB as against few KBs which apparently doesnt open up.

Sample data

```
[(13, 58), (13, 95), (0, 109), (13, 146), (39, 183), (26, 109), (39, 131), (52, 161), (26, 168), (39, 197), (52, 234), (52, 161), (78, 190), (104, 227), (26, 139)]
```

To convert the above string I'm using eval() function, which converts the string into a list.

Can someone figure out what is causing this issue?

```
data = os.path.join(datapath, filename)
norm_data = []
with open(data, 'r') as rf:
    data = rf.readlines()
    for d in data:
        d = eval(d)
        temp_list = []
        for n in d:
            (a, b) = float(n[0]),float(n[1])
            temp_list.append((a, b))
        norm_data.append(temp_list)
d = []
d_temp = []
rows = len(norm_data)
cols = len(norm_data[0])

with open(os.path.join(datapath, target_file), 'w+') as wf:

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            temp = np.subtract(norm_data[i][j], norm_data[i][0]) / 
                   np.linalg.norm(np.subtract(np.mean([norm_data[i] 
                   [8],norm_data[i][11]]), norm_data[i][0]))
            d_temp.extend(temp)
        d.append(d_temp)

    wf.write(str(d)+'\n')
```

Comment: The only time you write to the file is `wf.write(str(d)+'\n')`, so `d` must be really, really big.  Have you tried adding some debugging messages to your loop, so you can get an idea of how many times the loop is executing?

Comment: the first loop runs for 494 times, that is total number of lists in the file.

Comment: You never "reset" `d_temp` -- it seems like you should move `d_temp = []` in between the two `for` loops in the second `with open(...)` block.

Comment: How many pairs in each row? How big are these numbers?

Comment: @jedwards, you are right on spot, that solves the problem. Thank you.